Faced issue in access the protected storage context database while secure Startup option is enabled
In my app, i tried to access some encrypted storage database values after user-unlock.
Encrypted storage database created by this context: Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()
My app can access the database without any issues initially. But after I set a pin in the device with Secure Start-up option as yes, the app can't access data which previously stored.
I tried to print all the data from the db. But empty table cursor is returned.
The issue can be resolved if removed that passcode or set a new password with Secure Start-up option as No.
Kindly help me to resolve this case.
Device : Zebra TC72(issue occurring in all the android devices which are showing Secure Start-up option screen while configure a password.)
Also can reproduce this issue constantly.
